# What is the correct way to kill a vncsession in linux?

Tags: vnc, vncserver

When I run the following command in my remote `linux` box that I connect to from my `windows 7` laptop via `VNC` I get the following :

```
 [subhrcho@slc04lyo ~]$ ps -ef|grep vnc
subhrcho 20113 19804  0 21:40 pts/8    00:00:00 grep vnc
subhrcho 27486     1  0 Jan28 ?        00:05:35 Xvnc :1 -desktop slc04lyo:1 (subhrcho) -httpd /usr/share/vnc/classes -auth /home/subhrcho/.Xauthority -geometry 1680x1050 -depth 16 -rfbwait 30000 -rfbauth /home/subhrcho/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5901 -pn
subhrcho 27493     1  0 Jan28 ?        00:00:00 vncconfig -iconic
```

How can I kill this session elegantly ? I know `kill -9 <pid>` would do it but I think that is a forceful clean and might lead to corrupted files .

P.S: I also read [from this source](http://linux.die.net/man/1/vncserver) to use the kill option from vncserver but not sure how to figure out display#.

Answer (score 41):

As you noticed, from the `man vncserver`:

```
  -kill :display#
          This kills a VNC desktop previously started with vncserver. It does
          this by killing the Xvnc process, whose process ID is stored in the
          file "$HOME/.vnc/host:display#.pid". It actually ignores anything
          preceding a ":" in its argument. This can be useful so you can write
          "vncserver -kill $DISPLAY", for example at the end of your xstartup
          file after a particular application exits.
```

The display number is connected to the port number of the display if one hasn't set that manually (and differently), where

```
Display number = (Port number) ‒ 5900
```

e.g. port 5901 → display :1. This information can be found in `man Xvnc` (`vncserver` is just a wrapper script that calls this tool) where it says:

```
   -rfbport port
          Specifies the TCP port on which Xvnc listens for connections from
          viewers (the protocol used in VNC is called RFB - "remote
          framebuffer").  The default is 5900 plus the display number.
```

If you don't know the number by heart (but you need to know it if you are going to connect to the server anyway), you can check e.g. `ps ax | grep vnc` for information. If I do that locally, I see the processes

```
25697 ?        S     55:38 Xvnc4 :1 [...]
[...]
30481 ?        S     17:57 Xvnc4 :2 [...]
```

and thus I know that they represent VNC servers with display numbers `:1` and `:2` respectively, and can be killed by

```
vncserver -kill :1
vncserver -kill :2
```

In your case, you see that the display number is `:1` for the server listed in your `ps` output.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the answer above and it didn't work for me. It gave me an error message as in this question:
[Killing VNC Process Manually](https://superuser.com/questions/909400/killing-vnc-process-manually)

So I had to kill them manually. I tried kill -9, and then I couldn't log in with rdp anymore. I got `xrdp_mm_process_login_response: login failed` when I tried to log in.

The answer was found here:
http://linuxtoolkit.blogspot.com/2013/03/xrdpmmprocessloginresponse-login-failed.html

Basically, there is a session file not cleaned up when the Xvnc server is killed. The file is named for the display, so if you're on display :12, it's `/tmp/.X11-unix/X12`. Delete that file after `kill -9` and you're back in business.

Comment: Script I wrote to auto-kill idle sessions: https://gist.github.com/mnebuerquo/e825530cf2bfd363b6c3cd82fe697d94