# list active VNC connections from terminal

Tags: macos, connection, osx-mountain-lion, vnc

I am looking for a way to list all the active VNC connection to a machine. 
I know I can get all the active connection of the machine by running  `netstat -na` but I don't know how to filter just the connection for the VNC server.
I am running OSX 10.8.3 , any hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VNC runs on port 5900 by default, so you should be able to do:

```
netstat -na | grep '[:.]5900'
```

(OS X uses `.` as a port delimiter, but on Linux it's `:` — the pattern above will match both)

Example on my OS X machine:

```
% netstat -na | grep '[:.]5900'
tcp4       0      0  *.5900                 *.*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0  *.5900                 *.*                    LISTEN
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are running [xrdp](http://www.xrdp.org/) to connect to vnc, then 5900 will not show all the connections.  Here is a slightly different answer:

```
netstat -na | grep '[:.]5900'
```

gives:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5918          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5919          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5913          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5914          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5915          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5916          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5917          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5913          127.0.0.1:54546         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:54546         127.0.0.1:5913          ESTABLISHED
```

Also see [this answer for how to dig the port out of the process](https://superuser.com/questions/549386/what-is-the-correct-way-to-kill-a-vncsession-in-linux).