# Killing VNC Process Manually

Tags: ubuntu, vnc, tightvnc

I'm looking for a way to reset the display counter for VNC to :1.

What has happened is that my server has been restarted without killing the VNC processes first and upon reboot and then starting vncserver once more with a new process it has started at :2, completely ignoring :1.

On trying to kill :1 it says: "You'll have to kill the Xtightvnc process manually".

I cannot kill this process, there is no pid files for this display to delete and the process has long gone as the server has restarted. Please can someone advise me on how to restart this count back to :1. Can anyone please help me reset these settings.

Using tightvncserver on Ubuntu 14.01

Comment: The server has restarted, but the process is still there? Sounds like there's a lock file of sorts left around.

Comment: I've looked through all the running processes by running 'ps aux | less' but the old processes are definitely no longer there. I do think that is the case but I don't have much idea as to where the lock files are

Comment: Have you tried `vncserver -kill :2`?

Comment: 2 will kill fine but I cannot to kill 1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try running

```
ps -ef | grep vnc
```

to see which VNC services are running.

Comment: This was the answer that led me to the answer thank you sir! I didn't realise that everytime I rebooted my server that Virtual Machine Manager would assign monitors for VNC as it saw fit to my Virtual Machines.

Comment: Can you please elaborate so that this answers the question?

Answer (score 1):

As @bob has mentioned use the command -

> ps -ef | grep vnc

It will list all the vnc related process that are in running state.

So note down the PID of the process having the name

> Xvnc

And execute the command kill -9 <PID of Xvnc Process(es)>

I will kill the VNC server.

Then restart the VNC server and things are back.

Comment: the tightVNC says I have a vnc running but ps reports no vnc

Answer (score 0):

I solved typing on TightVNC `IPSERVER:2` instead of `IPSERVER:1`. On Vultr cloud, for example, there is another access to ubuntu desktop that is '*View Console*'.

Answer (score -1):

The following terminal command;

```
$ sudo tightvncserver -kill :1
```

Kills the first server session and leaves the second session untouched.

Comment: this just repeats the OPs error "You'll have to kill the ..."